# Need assistance with creating a cookie that will keep the current background and text colour

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a website that has a feature which allows the user to change the background colour, I would like to make a cookie that keeps the current colour selections when on all pages that have this feature. I'm not sure how i would go about doing this. I have used cookies in the past but this was years ago, and I no longer have access to that code meaning i am unable to repurpose it for my current needs.

The code below shows the HTML and JavaScript that I have used to change the colour of the background and text:

```
<form id="color_change_form" name="color_change_form" method="post">

  <label for="color_change">Select Background Colour</label>
  <select name="color_change_dd" id="color_change_dd">

    <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
    <option value="#000000">Black</option>
    <option value="#CFBD1F">Yellow</option>
    <option value="#B9B537">Celery</option>
    <option value="#92A62B">Grass</option>
    <option value="#7FA78F">Jade</option>
    <option value="#73A8BA">Aqua</option>
    <option value="#7694B6">Sky</option>
    <option value="#8A759C">Purple</option>
    <option value="#BB5988">Magenta</option>
    <option value="#CDACA5">Pink</option>
    <option value="#CFA34A">Orange</option>
    <option value="#C5BAB4">Grey</option>

  </select>

  <input type="button" name="color_change_confirm" id="color_change_confirm" value="Set" onclick="myFunction()" />

</form>


<script>
  function myFunction() {

    var e = document.getElementById("color_change_dd");

    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = strUser;

    localStorage["bgcolor"] = strUser;

    // document.getElementById("current_color").innerHTML = strUser;

  }
</script>
```

```
<form id="text_change_form" name="text_change_form" method="post">

  <label for="text_change">Select Text Colour</label>
  <select name="text_change_dd" id="text_change_dd">

    <option value="#000000">Black</option>
    <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
    <option value="#CFBD1F">Yellow</option>
    <option value="#B9B537">Celery</option>
    <option value="#92A62B">Grass</option>
    <option value="#7FA78F">Jade</option>
    <option value="#73A8BA">Aqua</option>
    <option value="#7694B6">Sky</option>
    <option value="#8A759C">Purple</option>
    <option value="#BB5988">Magenta</option>
    <option value="#CDACA5">Pink</option>
    <option value="#CFA34A">Orange</option>
    <option value="#C5BAB4">Grey</option>

  </select>

  <input type="button" name="text_change_confirm" id="text_change_confirm" value="Set" onclick="myFunction2()" />

</form>


<script>
  function myFunction2() {

    var e = document.getElementById("text_change_dd");

    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    document.body.style.color = strUser;

    localStorage["textcolor"] = strUser;

    // document.getElementById("current_color").innerHTML = strUser;

  }
</script>
```

I would appreciate if someone could offer some example JavaScript code for the required solution.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to recommend using `localStorage` instead, which it seems you are doing.

Finish your `localStorage` implementation like so; here I've added a call to `myFunction2` to the `document.body.onload` listener, and loaded the color from `localStorage`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction2()">
    <!-- <input type="text" id="start" placeholder="start"><br> <input type="text" id="end"><br> <button id ="generate" onclick="run()">Click to Generate</button> -->
    <form id="text_change_form" name="text_change_form" method="post">

      <label for="text_change">Select Text Colour</label>
      <select name="text_change_dd" id="text_change_dd">

        <option value="#000000">Black</option>
        <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
        <option value="#CFBD1F">Yellow</option>
        <option value="#B9B537">Celery</option>
        <option value="#92A62B">Grass</option>
        <option value="#7FA78F">Jade</option>
        <option value="#73A8BA">Aqua</option>
        <option value="#7694B6">Sky</option>
        <option value="#8A759C">Purple</option>
        <option value="#BB5988">Magenta</option>
        <option value="#CDACA5">Pink</option>
        <option value="#CFA34A">Orange</option>
        <option value="#C5BAB4">Grey</option>

      </select>

      <input type="button" name="text_change_confirm" id="text_change_confirm"
        value="Set" onclick="myFunction2()" />

    </form>


    <script>
      function myFunction2() {
        var e = document.getElementById("text_change_dd");
        

        var strUser = e != null && e.selectedIndex ?
                        e.options[e.selectedIndex].value :
                        localStorage["textcolor"];
        if(strUser) {

          document.body.style.color = strUser;
          
          localStorage["textcolor"] = strUser;
        }
      
        // document.getElementById("current_color").innerHTML = strUser;
    
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason you'd use localStorage instead of cookies is because localStorage has to be manually cleared by the user or overwritten by the webpage, whereas cookies can expire or be removed server-side and are therefore a bit less durable. Cookies are also transported back and forth between the server and client, so if the data needs to only matters to the client, use localStorage or sessionStorage.

Generally, if some piece of state has to do with user preferences, web storage is the best bet (since the server doesn't need this information -at all-).

If you need to track state (i.e., the user clicked this on this page, the user logged in as this, the user completed this part of the process, etc...) use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an extract from here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

You can use the following code to set a cookie:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

And thus retrieve it

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```